# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un reporte que hice en el reporteador de Devexpress?

Tags: c#, reportviewer, devexpress, report

Buen día.
Tengo un sistema desktop en desarrollo en el cual tengo un menú de reportes que yo realicé y que el usuario puede ejecutar pasando parametros, sin problemas.

Pero como el usuario quiere poder modificar esos reportes(colores, fuente, etc), agregué el reporteador de Devexpress. Comprendo que puedo guardar mi archivo .repx y buscarlo desde el reporteador. Mi problema es poder abrir desde el menú ese reporte modificado.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias.

Comment: Hola Dalia, te recomiendo que no emplees Devexpress, bueno a menos que quieras pagar mas de 800 dólares por la licencia, después de su versión de pruebas (algo de 30 días) van a inhabilitar prácticamente todo tu proyecto, y es todo un lío porque sus librerías se quedan en casi todos los controles, yo tuve que desinstalar y volver a instalar mi visual studio.

Comment: ¿Qué tal Jorge? Pues creo que no es tanto un problema, lo paga la oficina... entonces hay que sacarle jugo a lo que se tiene para trabajar. :)

Comment: No todos trabajamos con software sin licencia. Aparte, yo trabajo con DevExpress y ningún problema, es muy buena suite de controles.

Comment: Es Winforms? Web? Hay un control llamado ReportViewer, y puedes asignarle el reporte y te lo muestra en pantalla, pero ya depende de la plataforma.

Comment: Hola Luis. Sí, es Winforms... pero si le asigno un un sólo reporte, sólo me abrirá el modificado, y el detalle es que tengo varios reportes. Cómo te comentaba, puedo abrirlo desde el reporteador por medio del diálogo, pero al momento de querer abrirlo por medio de mi sistema, es donde me abre el que tengo por default.