# ¿Cómo ejecutar un reporte editado en un reporteador?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer, devexpress

Buen día.

Sigo sin resolver mi problema con respecto a mi entrada anterior:
[¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un reporte que hice en el reporteador de Devexpress?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157612/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-ejecutar-un-reporte-que-hice-en-el-reporteador-de-devexpress).

Así que voy a mostrar con imágenes lo que intento hacer:

- Este es mi reporte original.

[image: El reporte de mi sistema.]

- El usuario debería de tener la facilidad de editar el reporte en cuanto a colores, fuentes, etc. Así que tiene la opción de abrir el reporte y hacer lo que quiera con él.

[image: Reporte abierto desde el reportviewer.]

- Después, el usuario debería de poder abrir el reporte desde los menús que tiene el sistema... pero se vuelve a abrir el reporte original.

[image: Menú de reportes.]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer es que el usuario pueda abrir el reporte editado a su gusto, porque digamos que va orientado a diferentes clientes y saben que en gustos, todos son diferentes. No me conviene estar haciendo versiones diferentes del sistema para que cambien simples colores.

Ojalá que alguien pueda ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: cómo tienes agregado el archivo de reporte en la solución?

Comment: De esta manera...   `var reporteSocioXNota = new MenuForm<Sieron.Win.Formularios.frmReportPreview>()
            {
                Titulo = "Reporte de Saldo de Cliente por Periodo.",
                Icono = Properties.Resources.report,
                EsContenido = true,
                EsDialogo = false,
                EsUnico = true,
                Parametros = new Object[] { typeof(Reportes.rptSocioSaldoNV), "REPORTECLIENTESVENDEDORNV"}
            }`

Comment: Es una librería que nosotros diseñamos @Luis, pero es cómo todo, creamos unas instancia del rpt y sólo asignamos valores.

Comment: Lo pregunto porque si es un reporte incrustado en el proyecto (tu librería) quizás no se guardan los cambios.

Comment: Los cambios en el .repx sí se guardan cuando lo modifico por medio del reporteador, lo sé porque si lo vuelves a abrir desde ahí, te abre el modificado... pero ya ves que en momento de ejecución, abre el Designer.cs, entonces abre el que tengo en explorador de soluciones, la plantilla que yo diseñé desde un principio.

Comment: Pero el archivo .repx está incrustado en el proyecto? el reporteador los guarda porque no está en ejecución la aplicación.

Comment: No, no está incrustado. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Cuando le das botón derecho en el archivo repx y le das propiedades, ¿que te sale en la opción "build action"? ¿como ler indicas al editor de reportes el archivo repx?

Comment: No puedo encontrar la propiedad "build action" :(

Comment: Generé el archivo y lo he guardado en una carpeta que se abre cuando busco en el editor de reportes.

Comment: Busca la propiedad como "Acción de compilación" por si tienes el VS en español. En cuanto a lo otro, me refería mas a cómo le indicas al editor de reportes, en tiempo de ejecución, en la opción donde el usuario selecciona editar reporte, de dónde jale el archivo repx.

Comment: Por alguna extraña razón, no tengo esa opción o quizá no entiendo dónde está... y es que yo generé todos los archivos .repx en una carpeta y cuando el usuario quiere tener acceso a ellos, simplemente abre el cuadro de diálogo, elige el reporte que quiere editar (saben cuál escoger porque tienen nombres muy particulares), y lo abren para editar.

Comment: A vale, pues entonces está un poco raro que no se modifiquen. La opción que te digo está en la ventana donde te salen todos los archivos del proyecto en visual studio, le das botón derecho a cualquier archivo y luego en propiedades.

Comment: Oh sí!! Ya la encontré... en "acción de compilación" dice "Compilación", y el archivo que abre es el .cs
Lo cambio por el .repx?

Comment: Los archivo .cs si deben tener compilación, yo me refería al archivo .repx, qué tiene en acción de compilación, si es que lo tienes agregado al proyecto.

Comment: Ah ya! El .repx no tiene ninguna acción...

Comment: @Luis, ¿sabes qué acción debe tener el .repx?